# Substitute ReadWriteLock with AtomicReference for non-blocking operations

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I wrote this class to reload a `DataSource`, used by the entire application, when the persisted configuration data changes.
As you can see it is managed by `CDI` and exposed as a `Singleton`, and the "configuration changed" event arrives through the `configurationReload(...)` method, but that's not relevant now.

The reference update is guarded by a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, but I'm wondering if it is needed at all.

```
@Singleton
@ThreadSafe
class ReloadingDataSource implements DataSource {
    private final ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
    private final Lock writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();

    @GuardedBy("readWriteLock")
    private DataSource delegateDataSource;

    @Inject
    ReloadingDataSource(@Nonnull final Configuration configuration) {
        delegateDataSource = createDataSource(configuration);
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource(final Configuration configuration) {
        ... Create a ComboPooledDataSource using properties extracted from Configuration.
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        readLock.lock();

        try {
            return delegateDataSource.getConnection();
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    ...

    private void configurationReload(
            @Observes @Reload final ConfigurationChanged configurationChanged,
            @Nonnull final Configuration configuration) {
        final ConfigurationEvent event = configurationChanged.getConfigurationEvent();

        if (event.getType() != AbstractFileConfiguration.EVENT_RELOAD && !event.isBeforeUpdate()) {
            return;
        }

        writeLock.lock();

        try {
            destroyDelegateDataSource();
            delegateDataSource = createDataSource(configuration);
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void destroyDelegateDataSource() {
        try {
            DataSources.destroy(delegateDataSource);
        } catch (final SQLException ignored) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

*If we ignore the cost of creating a new DataSource*, could the above strategy be substituted by an `AtomicReference<DataSource>`, as below?
It would result in better performing and easier to read code.

Are there better ways to handle this which I'm not aware of?

```
@Singleton
@ThreadSafe
class ReloadingDataSource implements DataSource {
    private final AtomicReference<DataSource> delegateDataSource;

    @Inject
    ReloadingDataSource(@Nonnull final Configuration configuration) {
        delegateDataSource = new AtomicReference<>(createDataSource(configuration));
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource(final Configuration configuration) {
        ... Create a ComboPooledDataSource using properties extracted from Configuration.
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return delegateDataSource.get().getConnection();
    }

    ...

    private void configurationReload(
            @Observes @Reload final ConfigurationChanged configurationChanged,
            @Nonnull final Configuration configuration) {
        final ConfigurationEvent event = configurationChanged.getConfigurationEvent();

        if (event.getType() != AbstractFileConfiguration.EVENT_RELOAD && !event.isBeforeUpdate()) {
            return;
        }

        // Updated as per eckes tip. Is this what you meant?
        final DataSource newDataSource = createDataSource(configuration);

        while (true) {
            final DataSource oldDataSource = delegateDataSource.get();

            if (delegateDataSource.compareAndSet(oldDataSource, newDataSource)) {
                destroyDelegateDataSource(oldDataSource);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void destroyDelegateDataSource(final DataSource oldDataSource) {
        try {
            DataSources.destroy(oldDataSource);
        } catch (final SQLException ignored) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me, if you can generate a new instance an atomic update is fine. In all cases however you need to consider when to destroy the old instance. The fact that no `getConnection` is going on does not mean that objects from that datasource are still in use. Depending on if you need to reference the old state or not you can move the createDataStore() out of the loop or even skip the compareAndSet.

Comment: as long as it isn't an issue having two data sources open simultaneously, yes, that should be fine.  note, however, that in your current impl, you could have multiple update calls fighting over the new version (if it is possible to get simultaneous update events).

Comment: @eckes You're right! I did miss this point. I owe you a coffee.

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes there may be multiple changes observed during the time of the "first" new DataSource creation. But I don't understant, which problem could this generate? I mean, the "second" and subsequent threads would just wait for obtaining the lock.

Comment: @eckes I updated the Atomic example as you suggested. Could you verify if I got right what you meant? Skip the compareAndSet because the reference update is atomic itself? This one isn't clear to me

Comment: are the configuration updates "ordered"?  if you start handling update1 and then update2 comes along (with "newer" info), you could end up in a situations where the final result is based on update1 and update2 changes are lost.

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes, updates are ordered. While handling update1 I'm inside the write lock scope, so if update2 comes along it waits at the writeLock.lock() until writeLock.unlock() is executed by update1. So update2 just override update1, as it follow the same code path. But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I'm talking about your new version, which has no write lock?

Comment: @jtahlborn Yeah sorry, my bad! What do you suggest in that case?

Comment: Yes the new version is like I suggested. I think you can do with no loop and use `getAndSet()` instead. It will also return the old value you need for destroying it (eventually). But I suspect especially if your change events are single threaded both are fast enough.

Comment: @eckes  the second option seems very broken to me, it seems this is doing some kind of a spin lock. suppose that this `if (delegateDataSource.compareAndSet(oldDataSource, newDataSource)) {` returns `true` - at this point there is no one stopping `delegateDataSource.get()` to proceed and in my understanding this have to be separate operations

Comment: @Eugene I'll wait for eckes reply because I'm getting lost and don't want to write nonsense.

Comment: @eckes The getAndSet seems fine, basically it wraps what I'm doing now

Comment: The spin on compareAndSet is a normal pattern for optimistic locking, it should work however it’s not needed in this case. (You would use it if you use the result of get to calculate something for the set (like in a counter)

Comment: I would also suggest to use some pooling datasource instead as this can better manage the state of open aka borrowed connections. However not sure which of them support the reconfigure cleanly.

Comment: @eckes I'm using a pooled implementation from C3P0. Reading the javadoc for destroy, it actually doesn't force resources to close. It also state that resources clean themself in finalization, so i could just dereference the old data source. Maybe...

Comment: @LppEdd If reconfig is seldom that should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require your updates to be handled in an ordered fashion, you still need locking on the reload method.  In which case, you can ditch the AtomicReference logic and just go with a volatile:

```
public class RDS {
  private volatile DataSource delegate;

  public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return delegate.getConnection();
  }

  private void reload(Configuration config) {
    DataSource old = null;
    synchronized(this) {
      old = delegate;
      delegate = createDataSource(config);
    }
    destroyDataSource(old);
  }
}
```

Note however, you still potentially have other issues where connections could still be in use for the old DataSource when you close it (mentioned in @eckes first comment on the question).  In order to fix that, you need something like a connection Pool with acquire/release type logic which closes the old delegate once all existing connections have been released.