# Use @ConfigurationProperties over non-managed @Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to benefit from `@ConfigurationProperties` fantastic facilities without needing to expose the bean into my context. It is not a problem of `@Primaries` and the like, I simply cannot expose another `Datasource` into the context. How can I achieve the following?

```
@ConfigurationProperties("com.non.exposed.datasource.hikari")
public DataSource privateHikariDatasource() {
    if (Objects.isNull(this.nonExposedDatasource)) {
        this.nonExposedDatasource = this.nonExposedDatasourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
    return this.nonExposedDatasource;
}
```

---

Thanks to the answer by @LppEdd, the final perfect solution is:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

public DataSource privateHikariDatasource() {
    if (Objects.isNull(this.nonExposedDatasource)) {
        this.nonExposedDatasource = bindHikariProperties(this.nonExposedDatasourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build());
    }
    return this.nonExposedDatasource;
}

//This does exactly the same as @ConfigurationProperties("com.non.exposed.hikari") but without requiring the exposure of the Datasource in the ctx as @Bean
private <T extends DataSource> T bindHikariProperties(final T instance) {
    return Binder.get(this.environment).bind("com.non.exposed.datasource.hikari", Bindable.ofInstance(instance)).get();
}
```

Then you can call your bean internally with `this.privateHikariDatasource()` to be used by your other beans.
Great thanks to @LppEdd!

Comment: Without needing to expose *what* bean?

Comment: The DataSource one. I mean the code shown above is placed on a @Configuration class, but Iit is not signaled as `@Bean` because I don't want to expose that Datasource to the context

Comment: When doing things like this make sure you also register a callback to close the connections when the application is stopped. Else you might leave open (tcp) connections, normally this would be handled due to the fact it is a bean.

Comment: I'm interested in your statement. It is not a bean, how can it affect me? I understand the Datasource implementation, as it is not custom, must have some kind of postdestroy or something, or am I very wrong?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being that this `DataSource` is private to a class, and that containing class **can be/is** inside the Spring context, you can have a `@ConfigurationProperties` class

```
@ConfigurationProperties("com.foo.bar.datasource.hikari")
public class HikariConfiguration { ... }
```

Which, by registering it via `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, is available for autowiring

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HikariConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application { ... }
```

And thus can be autowired in the containing class

```
@Component
class MyClass {
   private final HikariConfiguration hikariConfiguration;  
   private DataSource springDatasource;

   MyClass(final HikariConfiguration hikariConfiguration) {
      this.hikariConfiguration = hikariConfiguration;
   }

   ...

   private DataSource privateSingletonDataSource() {
      if (Objects.isNull(this.springDatasource)) {
         this.springDatasource = buildDataSource(this.hikariConfiguration);
      }

      return this.springDatasource;
   }
}
```

`buildDataSource` will **manually** construct the `DataSource` instance.
Remember that you need to take care of synchronization when building the `DataSource`.

---

Final response is that you cannot re-use `DataSourceProperties`. You can't even extend it to change the properties' prefix. Only a single instance of it can exist inside the context.
The best you can do is mimic what Spring does.

Having

```
com.non.exposed.datasource.hikari.url=testUrl
com.non.exposed.datasource.hikari.username=testUsername
com.non.exposed.datasource.hikari.password=testPassword
...
```

You can define a new `@ConfigurationProperties` class

```
@ConfigurationProperties("com.non.exposed.datasource")
public class NonExposedProperties {
    private final Map<String, String> hikari = new HashMap<>(8);

    public Map<String, String> getHikari() {
        return hikari;
    }
}
```

Then, autowire this properties class in your `@Configuration`/`@Component` class.
Follow in-code comments.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfiguration {
    private final NonExposedProperties nonExposedProperties;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    CustomConfiguration(final NonExposedProperties nonExposedProperties) {
        this.nonExposedProperties= nonExposedProperties;
    }

    public DataSource dataSource() {
        if (Objects.isNull(dataSource)) {
            // Create a standalone instance of DataSourceProperties
            final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = new DataSourceProperties();

            // Use the NonExposedProperties "hikari" Map as properties' source. It will be
            // {
            //    url      -> testUrl
            //    username -> testUsername
            //    password -> testPassword
            //    ... other properties
            // }
            final ConfigurationPropertySource source = new MapConfigurationPropertySource(nonExposedProperties.getHikari());

            // Bind those properties to the DataSourceProperties instance
            final BindResult<DataSourceProperties> binded =
                    new Binder(source).bind(
                            ConfigurationPropertyName.EMPTY,
                            Bindable.ofInstance(dataSourceProperties)
                    );

            // Retrieve the binded instance (it's not a new one, it's the same as before)
            dataSource = binded.get().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
        }

        // Return the constructed HikariDataSource
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have any way to do this without having to duplicate the HikariDatasource.class implementation (which is really convenient as HikariConfig parent for me) into the HikariConfiguration.class? Id like to reuse HiakriDatasource.class provided schema in order to make it cleaner

Comment: @Whimusical Why would you have to duplicate the HikariDatasource class? Inside buildDataSource you can use whatever you want, it just has to return a DataSource.

Comment: Because my line `this.nonExposedDatasourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build()` returns a HikariDatasource instance, which indeed extends HikariConfig class, which has the official schema and getters/setters for the properties I am injecting as `com.non.exposed.datasource.hikari`

Comment: If my code worked well, I don't need to care about what is the particular implementation for HikariProperties in the future

Comment: @Whimusical being that you aren't letting Spring build a Bean itself, you need to manually use setters to construct the HikariDatasource. Automatic injection of properties won't work.

Comment: @Whimusical setters will remain there basically forever. You can just change the property file, you'll be fine in any case. It's still a write-once-and-forget thing

Comment: @Whimusical and don't be scared about creating objects yourself. Spring cannot do everything. I do this kinda things often.

Comment: Thanks LppEdd, that is precisely what I am asking, a neat way to inject those properties. I mean the only thing I need functionally is the equivalent of adding @Bean to the snippet above, but without injecting the bean in the context. Having to duplicate Hikari properties implementation and the like, it's more cumbersome and less mantainable

Comment: @Whimusical could you post a pseudo-code of the entire class you're imagining? I'd like to have the full context. I need to understand where you'll use this DataSource also. The solution will be easier than what you think most probably.

Comment: I really appreciate but it's a really long topic, with lots of conditionals and autoconfiguration, needing context of Spring Batch and Spring Cloud, and the like. I know how to solve this with workarounds, but it's a theoretical question, I am just wondering if Spring has any way to inject properties to a non-@Bean instance with a mechanism similar to `@ConfigurationProperties`. The only alternative solution that would satisfy me would be a way to expose my @Bean ONLY within the scope of my `@Configuration` class, but not outside (taken by autoconfigurations and conditionals)

Comment: @Whimusical I'll try to come up with something

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, LppEdd

Comment: @Whimusical could you post your this.nonExposedDatasourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build() method? Or is it the one from DataSourceProperties?

Comment: Good eye, yes, it is generated from an autowired org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties (this I can make it managed in my system)

Comment: @Whimusical and how do you create this DataSourceProperties? Is it the default one?

Comment: Yes, in this case I don't have multiple instances, I am only using Spring's autconfigured instance

Comment: @Whimusical see updated answer. Let me know if it is okay for you. That's basically how Spring does it. That was crazy hard to find out and code, but at least I've learned something.

Comment: That's an amazing effort! I really thank you for the help

Comment: @Whimusical try it out if you want and let me know if you have problems with it.

Comment: I edited the question details with the final solution with your idea customized and optimized for my case! Just one last question, why did you tell me "Remember that you need to take care of synchronization when building the DataSource". Is it really necessary? I understand the configuration bean is singleton, and I assume Spring does call the beans in a synchronized manner, or does it use several threads to load them?

Comment: @Whimusical multiple objects might have gotten hold of your `Configuration`/`Component` class instance. And Spring does live in a multi-thread environment (JVM), so yeah, keep it synchronized. I had a similar requirement months ago, so check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707808/substitute-readwritelock-with-atomicreference-for-non-blocking-operations

Comment: @Whimusical btw, you coded a nice, clean solution. Good job