# @ConfigurationProperties does not use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring-boot

`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` works for my `@Value`s but not used for the following advertised datasource configuration

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

I customized `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to decode passwords in configuration file but decoding functionality is not triggered for this exact place, while it works in other places. Could you please advise?

Comment: Were you able to solve?

Comment: workaround by for injecting `@Value`s and constructing data source from those resolved values

Comment: Okay, I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had few other obstacles and lean to dumb workaraund.

Answer (score 2):

By default Spring will use a simple/non-wrapped `ConfigurationPropertySource` instead of the more complex `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, which holds multiple `PropertySource`s.

An example can be found inside `DataSourceBuilder` itself

```
private void bind(DataSource result) {
    ConfigurationPropertySource source = new MapConfigurationPropertySource(this.properties);
    ConfigurationPropertyNameAliases aliases = new ConfigurationPropertyNameAliases();
    aliases.addAliases("url", "jdbc-url");
    aliases.addAliases("username", "user");
    Binder binder = new Binder(source.withAliases(aliases));
    binder.bind(ConfigurationPropertyName.EMPTY, Bindable.ofInstance(result));
}
```

For that snippet, normally `this.properties` is populated using the `DataSourceProperties` *Bean*, which is a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class DataSourceProperties implements BeanClassLoaderAware, InitializingBean {
```

---

The thing is, `@ConfigurationProperties` map 1:1 to a properties file, it is very opinionated.
`@Value` is a different beast.

---

I tackled a completely custom implementation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248571/use-configurationproperties-over-non-managed-bean/55248829#55248829) answer.
You might find it valuable.